# Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation

Tags: java

Can we get the properties file value in `sendRedirect();`

```
response.sendRedirect("<%=p.getProperty("eservice.dbkl.domain")%>?userid="+userid);
```

getting error like this

> Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation

Please give me the solution to get the properties file value in `sendRedirect();`

Comment: Skip the quotation marks or add **+** to concatenate.

Comment: You forgot to concatenate the string for domain: `response.sendRedirect("<%=p.getProperty("+eservice.dbkl.domain+")%>?userid="+userid);` should do the trick

Comment: Please look at the color-coding of the code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Why embed scriptlet code into a method call like that? Just put the code directly in there. Also your string concatenation is broken. Try this:

```
response.sendRedirect(p.getProperty("eservice.dbkl.domain") + "?userid=" + userid);
```